# How to use Socket.io in aws lambda functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, socket.io, aws-lambda

I'm using node js with aws lambda functions for my web application. I want to use web socket in my web app. And socket.io is a very famous library for node.js.

But I'm not sure how can I use it in aws lambda. can anyone let me know how to do it, is it possible using lambda functions?

Comment: Using socket.io in AWS lamba is not possible and also not a good option.  For socket programming we open a connection , we cannot predict when the connection will be closed. AWS lambda billing is based on the  time the function executes. Also we cannot execute a function  for more than 5 mins .
Will affect the cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't use socket.io with lambdas. Lambdas have a limit on time it can be executed, so holding open connection with a client is impossible.

What you can do though is use SNS. Lambdas can publish messages to SNS topics and lambdas can be invoked with SNS.

Comment: can you let me know more on this. It will be really helpfull.

Comment: Create new question with specifically what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround exists for this - it's the [WebSockets over MQTT in AWS IoT](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/01/aws-iot-now-supports-websockets-custom-keepalive-intervals-and-enhanced-console/). This way you can execute your Lambda functions from open socket connections.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, [AWS API Gateway supports WebSockets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-overview.html).
Unfortunately, I didn't manage to connect via socket.io since it generates a custom URL with additional params: /?EIO=3&transport=polling&sid=< id>

But I've found tiny WebSocket wrapper sockette ([used this tutorial](https://codeburst.io/how-to-build-a-react-chat-app-with-aws-api-gateway-websockets-and-cognito-custom-authorizer-6f84f2da47ec)), and it works fine!